# How to write a .py file from an existing python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I am just messing around with the idea of writting a .py file using my python script and then import it into a anothe script for reading purposes.

Here is the code:

```
f=open(filename,'w')
```

`f.write('data=[{}]'.format(data))
f.close()`

and then I am importing the file in another script and gives me the error:

TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Any Ideas on how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: At the very least, use `{!r}` instead of `{}` to get the `repr()` of `data`.  If you do that, this will at least have a *chance* of working properly.  In the general case, you probably want to use `pickle` or `json` for this.

Answer (score 9):

It should work in principle. You can even import it to the same script. The problem probably is with the `data`. When you try the following (full) example...

```
#!python3

fname = 'generated.py'
data = 5

with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write('data = [{}]'.format(data))

import generated
print(generated.data)
```

It will print...

```
[5]
```